# Jquery modal popup window in MVC

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, modalpopups

Is Jquery modal-dialog popup the best solution for creating popups that will work across all major browsers?

Comment: there are other `popup plugins` too, whereas `jquery popup` belongs to `jquery-ui`. You can choose your own..

Comment: Have you looked at `twitter-bootstrap`?  That also has 'modal' dialogs.

Comment: You mention MVC in the title, but no MVC tag - is this asp.net-mvc? If so, which version? jquery-ui modal dialogs look nice with asp.net-mvc, but it's not straight-forward out of the box functionality.

Comment: jquery-ui is generally [browser compatible](https://jqueryui.com/browser-support/), but asking on SO for "the best" is off topic as it's opinion based, perhaps you could reword your question before it gets downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I have discovered Bootstrap Modal popups and they work great in my design. They are very simple to implement and are very clean.